# Why isn't my mongodb install working correctly?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to install MEAN stack components. So I tried to install mongodb. The packages from the repository installed correctly but running it seems to have issues.

Post installation I tried:

```
sudo systemctl enable mongodb
```

which is resulted in:

```
● mongodb.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-10-27 15:22:36 EDT; 17min ago
 Main PID: 22947 (code=exited, status=14)
```

[image]

```
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

and then I tried: `sudo systemctl enable mongodb`

```
Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d mongodb defaults
Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d mongodb enable
Failed to execute operation: Operation not supported
```

Any idea why it is not starting? I can't figure it out. I am using Xubuntu 15.04.

Log File says:

```
2016-10-27T15:47:02.747-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=26138 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=System-Product-Name
2016-10-27T15:47:02.747-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.10
2016-10-27T15:47:02.747-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 79d9b3ab5ce20f51c272b4411202710a082d0317
2016-10-27T15:47:02.747-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
2016-10-27T15:47:02.747-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-10-27T15:47:02.747-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-10-27T15:47:02.747-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-10-27T15:47:02.747-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1404
2016-10-27T15:47:02.747-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-10-27T15:47:02.747-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-10-27T15:47:02.747-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2016-10-27T15:47:02.764-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=4G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2016-10-27T15:47:02.883-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2016-10-27T15:47:02.883-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-10-27T15:47:02.883-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-10-27T15:47:02.883-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2016-10-27T15:47:02.883-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-10-27T15:47:02.883-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-10-27T15:47:02.883-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2016-10-27T15:47:02.883-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-10-27T15:47:02.883-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-10-27T15:47:02.884-0400 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/var/lib/mongodb/diagnostic.data'
2016-10-27T15:47:02.884-0400 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
2016-10-27T15:47:02.918-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2016-10-27T15:48:23.409-0400 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 2 (Interrupt), will terminate after current cmd ends
2016-10-27T15:48:23.409-0400 I FTDC     [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture
2016-10-27T15:48:23.413-0400 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
2016-10-27T15:48:23.413-0400 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2016-10-27T15:48:23.413-0400 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 6
2016-10-27T15:48:23.413-0400 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 7
2016-10-27T15:48:23.413-0400 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2016-10-27T15:48:23.413-0400 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2016-10-27T15:48:23.413-0400 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2016-10-27T15:48:23.413-0400 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2016-10-27T15:48:23.511-0400 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2016-10-27T15:48:23.512-0400 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] dbexit:  rc: 0
```

Comment: Uhm, does the notion of a log file ring a bell? A meaningful excerpt (not the whole file) would be handy, if reading it doesn't solve the problem for you. Please use the [edit button](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40293040/edit) to add the excerpt. And OS. And versions. You get the picture.

Comment: I added it, sorry about that.